# Who will fix the vulnerabilities found in Firewall

Tags: firewalls, vulnerability

As a security guy, i run vulnerability scan and found vulnerabilities in firewall
Like as follows
SSL Server Allows Anonymous Authentication Vulnerability
Solution
SOLUTION:
Disable support for anonymous authentication.
1) Apache:
Typically, for Apache/mod_ssl, httpd.conf or ssl.conf should have the following lines:

My question is who has to fix this vulnerabilities: Is the the FW administrator or the Security guy who perform the scan

Comment: Pentesters break stuff, not fix it :)

Comment: So who should fix it?. Is the FW admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dr.Ü has no clue with such comment. Good pentesters break and **fix** stuff. Monkeys who just run tools are not considered pentesters.

Who should fix it? That really depends of the company's policy.

In one company it might be the sysadmin. In other company the network admin. In other company the security engineer. In other company the...

Comment: Thanks, So i will take it as the person who manages the device should fix it

Comment: I do not have a clue? Good pentesters TALK to the guy who's in charge of the system they are breaking and work together on a solution...